# How to control a youtube iframe sound through javascript/jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, iframe

I am looking to catch the sound provided in an iframe youtube video in order to stop/play it through a sound button.

Since the volume opt does not work anymore I tried this.

```js
function toggleSound() {
  var soundElem = document.getElementbyId("frame1") // also tried with iframe.getElementbyId()
  soundElem.volume = 0.3
  if (soundElem.paused) {
    soundElem.play()
  }
  else
    soundElem.pause()
}
```

```html
//my yt video
<iframe  id=iframe1 src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBECODE?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

// my volume btn
<div class=volume-button onmousedown=toggleSound();>
```

I can't get the youtube audio and the youtubeAPI does not provide me an event with an external button ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) you can use the [mute](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#mute) method to mute the sound with an external event:

```
var player

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
  })
}

function toggleSound() {
  if (player.isMuted()) {
    player.unMute()
  } else {
    player.mute()
  }
}
```